# Symmetric matrix 10 x 10

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, wolfram-alpha

Can You give me the example of symmetric matrix 10 x 10.

Or if You know online symmetric matrix generator then give me the links. I tried to make this with Wolfram Mathematica but I did not find a solution

Thanks a lot !

Comment: The $10\times 10$ identity matrix, or any diagonal matrix.

Comment: I mean dimension of the matrix 10 x 10

Comment: @Luchnik A $10\times 10$ identity matrix has dimension $10\times 10$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this easily with pen and paper. The algorithm is the following

1. Write down 10 numbers in a row
2. Beneath the $i$-th number (counting from $1$), write down a column of $10-i$ numbers
3. You've now found a lower triangular matrix
4. Complete the matrix to a symmetric matrix by copying the $j$-th number in the $i$-th row (if there *is* already such a number) to the $i$-th column of the $j$-th row (if there isn't already a number there).
5. Draw a large opening parenthesis to the left, and a large closing parenthesis to the right of your array of $10 \times 10$ numbers.
6. Ponder the fact that you could have easily figured this out yourself, had you bothered to look up the definition of a symmetric matrix.

(6) is the most important part of the algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Note that if $A$ is a square matrix, then $A+A^T$ is always symmetric where $T$ denotes transpose. In fact, $\frac{A+A^T}{2}$ is known as the symmetric part of $A$ (and $\frac{A-A^T}{2}$ the anti-symmetric part of $A$, and $A$ is the sum of its symmetric and antisymmetric parts).

In Matlab, you can use the following commands to get a random symmetric matrix:

A=randn(10);
matrix=A+A.';

[Of course, diagonal matrices are always symmetric, so you could do diag(randn(10,1)) or something as well to get a diagonal matrix with random Gaussian entries on the diagonal].

There is also sprandsym in matlab if you want sparse random symmetric matrices.

Comment: Thanks. but I haven't Matlab and I have no time to set up this. Can You use your software and post a couple of matrices here? Because I need only the examples

Comment: You can use Octave or Scilab - they are available freely in binary form for many platforms. You can also run that code here: http://lavica.fesb.hr/octave/octave-on-line_en.php

Comment: It gives me this http://fastpic.ru/view/63/2014/0509/807ff2be34fc3097203ad36dd3d4b948.jpg.html

Comment: If you're using Scilab, you may need: rand('normal');           A=rand(10,10);
A+A.'

Comment: Are there a functions to generate matrix with integers not longer then 100

Comment: Read the scilab manual or octave manual - for example, the randint function in Octave/Matlab, and note that the sum of two numbers between 0 and 50 is at most 100.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it's useful for you but I remember a matlab code for generating random symmetric positive definite matrix given in [How to generate random symmetric positive definite matrices using MATLAB?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357980/matlab-code-for-generating-random-symmetric-positive-definite-matrix)

Comment: Thanks. but I haven't Matlab and I have no time to set up this. Can You use your software and post a couple of matrices here? Thanks