# Simplest way of creating a positive (semi-) definite matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to construct an arbitrary $n\times n$ positive semi-definite matrix.
Maybe I can randomly create an $n\times m$ matrix and use its covariance matrix.
But I want to know if there's any other (efficient) way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: The problem is not trivial. See these questions on MSE and SO: [a](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357980/matlab-code-for-generating-random-symmetric-positive-definite-matrix), [b](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619335/a-simple-algorithm-for-generating-positive-semidefinite-matrices), [c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037340/how-to-generate-pseudo-random-positive-definite-matrix-with-constraints-on-the-o). See also [this article](http://www.math.wsu.edu/faculty/genz/papers/rndorth.ps) on random orthogonal matrices

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut thank you lots

Comment: Also [this one](http://staff.uni-ruse.bg/eveleva/positive_definite.pdf) on positive definite random matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try if this way works out for you:

Create a diagonal Matrix $M$ with diagonal entries $(\geq) > 0$. Then take an invertible matrix $P$ and calculate $E = PMP^{-1}$, hence E and M are similar, hence E is also positive (semi-) definit. Using this way you have to worry about finding arbitrary invertible matrices. One way for that would be to do random elementary row/column operations to the identity matrix(for that you can create elementary matrices by random, which is an easy task).

Comment: you're right thank you

Comment: what about using orthognal matrices $P$? One could generate them using gramm schmidt agorithm