# Does dropping off-diagonal elements from a positive semidefinite matrix preserve positive semidefinite property?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite

Let $M$ be a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix of size $n \times n$. Randomly drop any number of off-diagonal elements by setting them to zero on both the upper and lower triangle (keeping symmetry). Is the resulting matrix still positive semidefinite?

For example:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2.7732 & 0.670677 & 0.141774 \\
0.670677 & 2.50917 & 0.393801 \\
0.141774 & 0.393801 & 2.3329
\end{pmatrix}
\rightarrow
\begin{pmatrix}
2.7732 & 0.670677 & 0 \\
0.670677 & 2.50917 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2.3329 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is still positive semidefinite. I observed this numerically by generating matrices following [this algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/358092/38206), but it certainly may just be due to the distribution that those matrices came from.

The number of elements to drop on one of the sides is $r \in \{ 1, 2, \dots, n(n-1)/2 \}$.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on Yorch's counterexample: for any $n\ge3$ and any entrywise nonzero vector $u\in\mathbb R^n$, if we zero out any symmetric pair of off-diagonal entries from $M=uu^\top$, the resulting matrix is indefinite.

Let $Z$ be obtained from $M=uu^\top$ by setting the $(1,2)$-th and $(2,1)$-th entries to zero. Then $Z$ is indefinite because it has a positive diagonal but its leading principal $3\times3$ minor is negative:
$$
\det\pmatrix{u_1^2&0&u_1u_3\\ 0&u_2^2&u_2u_3\\ u_1u_3&u_2u_3&u_3^2}=-(u_1u_2u_3)^2<0.
$$

Answer (score 6):

The simplest counter I was able to find is:

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$

Has rank $1$ and $(1,1,1)$ is a $3$-eigenvector, so the spectrum is $\{[3]^1,[0]^2\}$ and the matrix is PSD.

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ has characteristic polynomial

$(1-x)( (1-x)^2 - 1) - 1(1-x) =  (1-x)((1-x)^2-2) = (1-x)(x^2-2x-1)$.

So the spectrum is $\{[1]^1,[1+\sqrt{2}]^1,[1-\sqrt{2}]^1\}$ and the matrix isn't PSD.

Note with $2\times 2$ there is no counter since after any step you'll get a diagonal matrix, and the entries on the diagonal of a PSD matrix are non-negative.

Comment: Thanks! It is obvious looking at it now. It just appeared numerically because the algorithm I had used to generate the pos. semi. def. matrices was generating diagonally dominant matrices - hence zeroing out off-diagonal elements it was still diagonally dominant and still pos. semi. def.

Comment: My pleasure. ${}{}$